# Name disappears in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn flutter and I've met a strange issue.
When I press overview button in my phone after opening my app for the second time the name disappears
[When I press overview button for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNnAf.jpg)
[When I press overview button for the second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHURK.jpg)

I tried to search for this problem all over the internet but I didn't find any answer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_with_login/screens/login.dart' as login;
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: login.Login(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see your main file dart code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can just add a `title` here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_with_login/screens/login.dart' as login;
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: login.Login(),
      title: "Your app name" // Add here
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```